# Wampserver unwanted content in HTML source

Tags: php, html, haml, wampserver

I have a local PHP website running by Wampserver on Windows 7. I don't know why but there is unwanted comment sections in my source all over on every page like seen on the image below:

[image]

The original source is a HAML file starting like this:

[image]

The same source is working for my colleagues so it must be something with my local webserver. 
**Any idea what could cause this?**

Comment: can you show me your original code?

Comment: Sure, I edit my question to see the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [HTML conditionals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) and are most likely generated by your IDE. No need to worry about them.

Comment: Yeah but there is one after every HTML node. Starting and ending node aswell. That's too much I think. And there are errors on the JS console because of this and there shouldn't be any.

Comment: ..and I'm not worried about the conditianal comments but the < !-- ( :) --> part between them.